# configure: error: Provided blacs does not work!

Tags: 20.04, docker

I'm trying ti install acousto on ubuntu 20.04 using acousto-2.0_dockerfile.
I used the follwing command : `sudo docker build -t acousto2.0 -f ./acousto-2.0_dockerfile .`
I got an error : `configure: error: Provided blacs does not work!`

Can you help me solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

try changing "debian" to "debian:8.6" in the dockerfile

( see https://sourceforge.net/p/acousto/discussion/852636/thread/ecebae1d2e/ )